# else code not working properly discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have tried to make a hug command on discord to hug the mentioned user. I set up a command to check if there has been a user mentioned. If I do not mention a user, it works as intended, but when mentioning a user, it outputs the same thing. Here is my code:

```
    if (message.mentions.users.length > 1) {

        const hug = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`${message.mentions.users.first().username} got a hug from ${message.author.username}!`, `${message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic:true })}`)
            .setImage(hugs[hugged])
            .setColor('#ffb9f4')
        message.channel.send(hug);

    } else {
        message.channel.send('Please mention a user to hug!');
    };
```

I don't think anything else should be needed but let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition checks if there is more than one user tagged, but you can check if there is any tagged users with

```
if (message.mentions.users == true)
```

Second problem is that users is a collection so you have to use .size instead of .length

```
if (message.mentions.users.size > 0)
```

Both are good.

Comment: Thank you! The first code, if(message.mentions.users == true would not work but changing length with size worked fine

Comment: My bad! A Collection (like other Objects in js) returns true even if empty so it couldn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in a guild, I'm pretty sure that all mentions are to a GuildMember, try setting your if statement to

```js
if(message.mentions.members.length > 1 || message.mentions.users.length > 1)
```